# Formula works in cell but not in conditional formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I have a list of Phone Extension, with their assigned phone number, and the users name, if in use. I'm trying to use conditional formatting to find extensions with a phone number, but no user, and highlight them in green.

I tested my formula in a cell first, and it works there, but when i put it in to conditional formatting for all of Column B. Nothing happens.

Here is my formula

```
=IF(AND(NOT(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,-1)=""), 
            OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0, 1)=""), TRUE, FALSE)
```

---

```
                 Current Outcome                                 Goal Outcome
```

[image] [image]

Comment: So you want the extension to be highlighted if the user is blank? 
SO teh condition is if extension present and the user not present then hightlight extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following formula:

> =AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A2)),ISBLANK(C2))

This uses the `AND` function to check if two conditions are true:

1. Cell A2 is **not** blank- `NOT(ISBLANK(A2))`
2. Cell C2 **is** blank- `ISBLANK(C2)`

Set this up for cell B2's conditional formatting. Then, go to Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules... and change the "Applies to" range to cover all of your column B values (e.g., =$B:$B)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that might make it easier. In the Excel Options, Formulas, check R1C1 reference style. Now you can select the range and use this R1C1 Formula:

```
=AND(RC[-1]<>"",RC[1]="")
```

When you uncheck "R1C1 reference style", the conditional Formating Formula will be back to A1 style:

```
=AND(A2<>"",C2="")
```